# Merge two dataset in R, with using one of the dataset as reference, and use several times

Tags: r

How can I merge dataset x and dataset y, where dataset y is a 'category reference', so I want to merge  these two dataset, and use dataset y as many time as needed. so like:

```r
dataset x: 
apple 3 
apple 4
banana 5
banana 6
apple 5
carrot 4
apple 3 
carrot 3

dataset y:
apple fruit
banana fruit
carrot vegetable
```

result I want:

```
apple 3 fruit
apple 4 fruit
banana 5 fruit
banana 6 fruit
apple 5 fruit
carrot 4 vegetable
apple 3 fruit
carrot 3 fruit
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of each of your data sets by `dput(head(data))` so you will have better chances of getting relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `left_join` from dplyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducing your data
x <- tibble(
  fruit = c("apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "apple", "carrot", "apple", "carrot"),
  count = c(3,4,5,6,5,4,3,3)
)

y <- tibble(
  fruit = c("apple", "banana", "carrot"),
  type = c("fruit", "fruit", "vegetable")
)

left_join(x, y, by = "fruit")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  fruit  count type     
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    
1 apple      3 fruit    
2 apple      4 fruit    
3 banana     5 fruit    
4 banana     6 fruit    
5 apple      5 fruit    
6 carrot     4 vegetable
7 apple      3 fruit    
8 carrot     3 vegetable
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` you could use `merge`.

```
fruit <- c("apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "apple", "carrot", "apple", 
count <- c(3,4,5,6,5,4,3,3)"carrot")
x <- data.frame(fruit, count)

fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "carrot")
type <- c("fruit", "fruit", "vegetable")
y <- data.frame(fruit, type)

merge(x, y, by = "fruit")
```